# PHP Worldpay Form Integration - prevent asking for customer details again

Tags: php, worldpay

I'm currently looking to integrate Worldpay into a custom shopping cart. (What a horrible system to integrate with.) Anyway, from the little information I can find i've opted for a simple form for sending the payment information over.

But worldpay seems to want to ask for my customers **cardholders details** again on the worldpay form. Can these at least be prefilled?

[image: Payment Form]

My code is (for example):

```
<form action="https://secure.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="100" />
  <input type="hidden" name="instId" value="XXX">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP">
  <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
</form>
```

I've dug around the WP documentation to no avail. Wish we'd opted for PayPal now!

Comment: Are you not able to use their API?

Comment: Well i'm not sure... I don't seem to have the options for the api. It's a UK account and a "Junior". Too late to call and find out so went down this route. Will check out the API tomorrow

Comment: Provided you have an API key: https://github.com/WorldPay/worldpay-lib-php

Comment: This looks much more like it - but looking at the account we have I don't think they work together... Might look to change the account over. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the name and address details as well. See integration examples here, example 05 has name and address fields > http://support.worldpay.com/support/bg/index.php?page=development&sub=integration&subsub=examples#basic

and look at this pdf, around page 21 http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/pdf/rhtml.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this - I stupidly missed this example when looking before. This is perfect for the Junior account, but I think i'm going to look at switching to the API.